# Availability of deprecated egrep and fgrep commands

Tags: grep, command, portability

Quite often I've seen answers mentioning that `egrep` is `grep -E` or `fgrep` is `grep -F` and using `egrep` or `fgrep` in their answers, even though these are technically deprecated.

So I was wondering if there were particular examples of modern(ish) unix-like systems which don't provide this link between the sets of commands. For example, the GNU grep manual contains

> In addition, two variant programs egrep and fgrep are available. egrep
>   is the same as ‘grep -E’. fgrep is the same as ‘grep -F’. Direct
>   invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated, but is provided to
>   allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.

while FreeBSD has

> In addition, two  variant programs egrep and fgrep are available. 
>   egrep is  the same  as grep -E.  fgrep is the same as grep -F.

It would be good to know that a script wouldn't necessarily work everywhere, even with the fact that `egrep` or `fgrep` could be removed tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there are any systems that explicitly *don't* have them (but I don't have any modern comercial UNIX systems to look at right now, just open-source systems), but there are quite a few where they are just stubs that call regular `grep` with the appropriate option.

For example, on Gentoo Linux, `/bin/egrep` is this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec grep -E "$@"
```

And `/bin/fgrep` is essentially the same.  I've also seen some systems where `egrep` and `fgrep` are just symbolic links or hard links to `grep`, but I have never seen one where neither of them eisted.

Note however that while `egrep` and `fgrep` are deprecated, they're almost certainly not going away any time soon.  A quick scan of scripts in `/usr` on my laptop (which is running Gentoo Linux) finds a few dozen software packages that have scripts which use one or the other, including such ubiquitous things as Python and GCC.

Given all this, one can rather ironically conclude that code that uses the deprecated commands instead of the options is actually *more* portable than code which uses the options, since it will run on older systems that code using the options won't.

Comment: “they're almost certainly not going away any time soon.” that’s kind of what I expected, for many other of the commands etc that have been mandated for posix too. Cheers for the comments.

Comment: While they haven't gone away, they now print deprecation warnings to stderr, which breaks scripts and is horribly annoying.